# Phpstorm smooth fonts

Tags: fonts, anti-aliasing, phpstorm, brackets

I'm using `Brackets 1.5` and `Phpstorm 10.0` on `Windows 10`.

In Phpstorm the fonts are not good and codes are hard to read. On the other hand, in brackets fonts are great. Apparently Brackets uses "sourcecodepro-medium" font. I downloaded https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro and installed the font but in Phpstorm I get weird characters. I tried other version of sourcecodepro, but the text doesn't seem as is shown in Brackets. I tried adding these lines:

> -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on
>
> -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
>
> -Dswing.aatext=true
>
> -Dsun.java2d.xrender=true

into "PhpStorm64.exe.vmoptions", but again no success.

I just want Phpstorm to use exact font being used in Brackets, in a smooth way.

Sorry for my bad English BTW.

Comment: Your operating system is Windows ? *Also I suggest you to add a screenshot with PhpStorm to your question*

Comment: IIRC there was a similar problem with NotePad++ and this [particular font](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/729).

Answer (score 1):

About the fonts showing weirdly. I had a similar issue in PHPStorm, after adding Source Code Pro. The solution came after I read this: http://sticksnglue.com/wordpress/source-code-pro-phpstorm-the-plot-thickens/

I just copied all the fonts to (in Windows) `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PhpStorm 10.0.1\jre\jre\lib\fonts`.

Restarted PHPStorm and it works now. However I wasn't able to make it more smooth.

Comment: It works for me, thx.